# Why is たform used before 方?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I found this sentence on the Bunpro website and I found it very confusing.

> 疲れている割には、かなり動けた方だと思います

My understanding of this sentence is something like "Despite being tired, I think (person) is more on the side of being able to move"

Why doesn't it say 動ける方だと思います?

Is this related to the construction "た方がいい"?

Comment: The reading was ほう and not かた, therefore I believe that the meaning was ~direction~ as in comparing it with something. That is why I wrote ~is more on the side of...~

Answer (score 2):

The た-form is used simply because the person *was* able to move on some concrete occasion such as a sports match.

If the sentence were describing the person's permanent quality as you supposed it did, it would say 動ける方.

Comment: So the meaning would be something like "Despite he being tired, I think (person) [was] more on the side of being able to move"? Is the tense still past even if the previous sentence isn't 疲れていた割には?

Comment: Does the tense work as in 宿題をしている最中に、電話が鳴りました？

Comment: @Manab - Yes, that's correct. Relative tense is used in the subordinate clause. 疲れていた割には means the same in this sentence, though.